# UICollectionView: remove separators for specific cells only

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewlayout

I need to show separators for every cell in `UICollectionView` except every first cell of a section. I'm using list layout.
So far I have only been able to remove all separators using `configuration.showsSeparators = false`.

My `UICollectionView` configuration:

```swift
let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let provider = { (_: Int, layoutEnv: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
        var configuration = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .grouped)
        configuration.showsSeparators = true // <----- shows separators for every cell
        configuration.footerMode = .supplementary
        return .list(using: configuration, layoutEnvironment: layoutEnv)
    }
    let listLayout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(sectionProvider: provider)
    return UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: listLayout)
}()
```

Cell registartion:

```swift
let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<MailboxCell, MailAccount> {
    (cell, indexPath, listItem) in
    // some setup code
}

dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Account, ListItem>(collectionView: collectionView) { 
    (collectionView, indexPath, listItem) -> UICollectionViewCell? in

    // some setup
    return collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: cellRegistration, for: indexPath, item: listItem)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration` has a handler closure which allows you to configure the separator appearance on an item-by-item basis: `itemSeparatorHandler` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionlayoutlistconfiguration/3727737-itemseparatorhandler).

If you don't want bottom separators for the first item in each section you can add a handler to your `UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration` that hides the separator for the first item:

```
let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let provider = { (_: Int, layoutEnv: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
        var configuration = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .grouped)
        configuration.footerMode = .supplementary

        // Hide bottom separator for first item in each section
        configuration.itemSeparatorHandler = { indexPath, sectionSeparatorConfiguration in
            var configuration = sectionSeparatorConfiguration
            configuration.bottomSeparatorVisibility = indexPath.row == 0 ? .hidden : .visible
            return configuration
        }

        return .list(using: configuration, layoutEnvironment: layoutEnv)
    }
    let listLayout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(sectionProvider: provider)
    return UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: listLayout)
}()
```

It looks like `showsSeparators` defaults to `true` for the grouped appearance so you don't need to explicitly set that.

If you also want to remove the top separator you can easily do that too by adjusting `topSeparatorVisibility` in the handler in the same way.

Comment: Looks great! The only concern I have is that `itemSeparatorHandler` is only available for iOS 14.5+. I guess the solution for older iOS versions would be what @OneCommentMan suggested: just add a line to the bottom of cells?

Comment: Your own line should work but getting the correct appearance and leading margin can be tricky. The separators are probably using `UIColor.separator` (which is partially  transparent). They are also 1 pixel, not 1 point, tall. You would need to set a fractional height constraint based on the 2x/3x resolution of the screen (i.e. 0.5 for 2x and 0.333 for 3x). `UICollectionViewListCell` has a `separatorLayoutGuide` but it looks like that might only be valid when the system's separators are enabled.

Comment: `separatorLayoutGuide` worked. It's actually valid even when separators are disabled. So all that's required to do here is constraint my fake separator to `separatorLayoutGuide` and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is remove the default separators by setting configuration.showsSeparators = false. Then add a line view at the bottom of the cell's UI to create the illusion of a separator.